# GWT and HTTP: Content-Disposition inline doesn't work

Tags: http, gwt, smartgwt

I'm trying to display PDF inlined in web page (actually generated by smartGWT). The page tries to load inside `iframe`.

```
<!-- language: java -->

      response.setContentLength(fileData.length);
      response.setContentType("application/pdf");
      response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; fileName=" + fileName);

      outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
      outputStream.write(fileData);
      outputStream.flush();
      outputStream.close();
```

**Generated HTML**

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<iframe height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="auto" 
        id="isc_GE" frameborder="0" 
        src="http://localhost:8080/pdfOperation.do?requestparams"></iframe>
```

But every time this `iframe` loads - I'm getting download window. It only worked for Chrome's embedded PDF viewer. But doesn't work with disabled chrome's PDF viever and firefox.

Comment: How about `<object>` and/or `<embed>` instead of `<iframe>`?

Answer (score 0):

That is because a Browser is no PDF viewer.

You can only inline a PDF into a view, if the browwser can render it.

Maybe, you can try PDF.js, to create an inline view.

Comment: No, I need inlined Adobe PDF reader. Because there is some PDF forms functionality. (which chrome PDF viewer doesn't support)

Comment: You did not write, that you'll need the Adobe reader. If you start the reader manually, does a dialog show. I had an issue with a very first start of the reader and the welcome dialog.

Comment: Then I actually don't understand how these embedded views are working.
I saw that when user opens page - inside loads embedded Adobe Viewer.